# Trading Elasticity Research

Tags: trading, fees

Is there any good research on the price elasticity of trading in financial markets? Things like optimal fee structures and the like?

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at this paper (December 2011):

http://www.peri.umass.edu/fileadmin/pdf/research_brief/PERI_FTT_Research_Brief.pdf

At the end of the paper you can also find an interesting reference list.